# StartCoroutine overhead vs Invoke (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, invoke, coroutine, ienumerator

I am comparing StartCoroutine and Invoke in a Method that should be execute in a specific time. To my understanding these two functions should take the same time (1 sec). Calling the first method with invoke completes in about 1sec, using a coroutine takes almost 2 seconds! How can that be?

```
private void iincrease_arrow_invoked(){
    if (arrow.transform.localScale.x <= 1f) {
        arrow.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (arrow.transform.localScale.x + 0.01f, arrow.transform.localScale.y, arrow.transform.localScale.z);
        Invoke ("iincrease_arrow_invoked", 0.01f);
    } 

}

IEnumerator increase_arrow_coroutine(){

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);
    if (arrow.transform.localScale.x <= 1f) {
        arrow.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (arrow.transform.localScale.x + 0.01f, arrow.transform.localScale.y, arrow.transform.localScale.z);
        StartCoroutine (increase_arrow_coroutine ());
    } 

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use e.g while loop instead of recursion in coroutine?

Comment: Shouldn't the `yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);` line be at the end of the coroutine? I don't know if that would make a difference

Comment: using a while loop takes 2sec as well for me.
yielding at the end keeps calling the coroutine and then waits, so basically it instantly perfroms the scaling.

Answer (score 1):

The `IEnumerator` is likely running more than once, while the invoked function is only running once. In your code, you're allowing the `IEnumerator` to be run multiple times by also calling `StartCoroutine` inside the `IEnumerator`.

Comparing `InvokeRepeating` with your existing `IEnumerator` would be a cleaner comparison.

Comment: I do still find it weird that using the second method uses so much more time and even using a while loop with the second method takes so much longer.

Comment: This is the nature of a coroutine in Unity; its internal handling and overhead is unknown, but there is additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically it's quite different since you are waiting a full second before doing anything at all in the coroutine, and then you do it, and when it executes itself again there you are waiting another full second. The Invoke call is executed immediately since you didn't put a delay on that like in the coroutine, and then you ask it to wait 1 second and repeat. If you want the coroutine to behave the same, then code it the same, and put the delay at the end.

A diagram would help:
StartCoroutine ->>> wait 1 second ->>> do the work ->>> wait 1 second when repeated.

What you want is this:
StartCoroutine ->>> do the work ->>> wait 1 second ->>> do the work when repeated

It only ***appears*** to be taking 2 seconds the way you have it.

This is more what it should look like before even beginning to compare them:

```
WaitForSeconds delay = new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);

IEnumerator increase_arrow_coroutine() {
    if(arrow.transform.localScale.x <= 1.0f) {
        arrow.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
            arrow.transform.localScale.x + 0.01f, 
            arrow.transform.localScale.y,
            arrow.transform.localScale.z);
    }

    yield return delay;

    StartCoroutine(increase_arrow_coroutine());
}
```

To me it still doesn't make much sense that it takes that long for you unless you have other delays somewhere else. It should only take 0.01 seconds, but that's another story.